# Lucene Paging with search

Tags: lucene, pagination

Hello I am currently using Lucene 4.6.1

In my design I need to be able to search and page possibly many results, so i have some general questions for optimization.

First in the "search(query q, int n)" What is the goal of the variable "n" , Is "n" different from ".totalHits()" ? How should this number be chosen and with what specifications?

Second, it seems that there are two general algorithms for paging. I can either use "searchAfter" or process the "ScoreDoc[]" given a page size.

Currently what way do most people recommend, and what are the design ideas that are required?

Answer (score 2):

searchAfter can be used for efficient "deep paging".

A tutorial on using it with Solr
http://heliosearch.org/solr/paging-and-deep-paging/

Answer (score 0):

The int passed to `search` is the maximum number of hits the search will retrieve.  `totalHits`, from the `TopDocs` is the total number of hits for the query.  It may be more or less than the value passed in.

Not clear to me what you mean by processing the `ScoreDoc` array.  `searchAfter` is specifically intended to be used for pagination.  Use it.